# How can I send back one preset field of data in an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, post

I am working on a Node.js website. It maintains data about districts in a province. To edit district data, the admin types the district's name and the year and goes to a form (`/edit?district=blah&year=2010`) that has various fields about the district. How should I track which district and year the form was filled out for in the POST route's scope?

Basically I want to send back data in the current URL's parameters with a form POST.

Comment: Are you sending this request on a node ??
Means you have set up a proxy URL where you are sending this request and want your node to handle this and give back the data in response according to the district and the year selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `?district=blah&year=2014` dynamically to the action field of my form and it works! I can get the two variables using `req.query.district` and `req.query.year` in the POST handler. Another way that people suggested to me was to have hidden input boxes on the page with the data pre-filled (using JS or any templating system you're using) and have it submit with the form.

Answer (score 1):

Require `body-parser` module in your node server.. Then u can get the parameters posted in the body like `request.body.paramName` in any of your routes with post method.

Comment: I know how to read the data from the form. I just want to send back more data that the user does not enter into the form.

Comment: can you explain more what u require?

Comment: I think my question does it pretty well. I am on a page with URL parameters. Said page contains a form. I want to submit the data in the current URL parameters *with* this form.